# Prove that there isn't a base of the $n \times n$, $(n > 1)$ real matrices space such that all of its $n^2$ matrices are commutative

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I tried to suppose for the matter of contradiction that there is such a base, so if $B$ is $n \times n$ matrix and let $A_i$ be a matrix from the base so there is a linear combination s.t.

$$ B = t_1 A_1 + t_2 A_2 + \dots + t_{n^2} A_{n^2} $$

where $t_1,\dots,t_{n^2}$ are scalars and $A_1,...,A_{n^2}$ are the base vectors (matrices) and since $A_iB = BA_i$ so
$$A_i(t_1A_1 + t_2A_2 + \dots + t_{n^2}A_{n^2})=(t_1A_1 + t_2A_2 + \dots + t_{n^2}A_{n^2})A_i,$$
but I don't know what should I do next.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you asking for a proof that matrices, no matter the basis, are not commutative? Or something else?

Comment: I clarified, or at least I hope I did

Comment: It still doesn't seem clear. Isn't it a fact that all vector spaces have a base? Are you talking about other types of bases (as in topological, for instance)?

Comment: what I am trying to say that there is no base that all of what it contains are commutative matrices

Comment: If there were such a basis of the real vector space of real n x n matrices, what would that say about taking products of arbitrary elements of that vector space?

Comment: Using both $a$ and $A$ is an extremely bad choice of notation

Comment: If $A_iB = BA_i$, then $CB = BC$ for every matrix $C$ and so $B=b I$. But not all matrices are a multiple of the identity matrix $I$, when $n>1$.

Answer (score 2):

Schur, for $K=\Bbb C$, and Jacobson, for arbitrary fields $K$, has proved, that there is a *commutative* subalgebra of dimension $r$ of algebra $M_n(K)$ of $n\times n$-matrices if and only if
$$
r <\left[ \frac{n^2}{4}\right] +1.
$$
So there isn't a base of the $n \times n$, $(n > 1)$ real matrices space such that all of its $n^2$ matrices commute.

Comment: That's a surprising answer and an interesting result. Thanks.